# How do you execute actions after the form is successfully processed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I want to make the form hide and a thank you message appear instead of it after the form is successfully submitted. I've done the below code but I cannot manage to get any action performed after the form is submitted .. it's like the 'if' function is ignored.

Below is my code:

JQuery:

```
$('form#contactform').submit(function(event) {

var formData = {

    //get form data
    'name' : $('input[name=name]').val(),
    'email' : $('input[name=email]').val(),
    'subject' : $('input[name=subject]').val(),
    'message' : $("#msg").val(),

};

$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'sendmail.php',
    data : formData,
    dataType : 'json',
    encode : true   
})

//Done promise callback
.done(function(data) {

    //log data to console
    console.log(data);

    //Errors and validation messages        
    if (! data.success == true) {

        $('section#contact form#contactform').hide;
        $('section#contact div.thxform').show;

    } else {

        alert("An internal error has occured");

    }

});

//Stop form default action
event.preventDefault();
```

Php:

```
<?php

$errors = array(); //array to hold validation errors
$data = array(); //array to pass back data

//validate variables
if (empty($_POST['name']))
    $errors['name'] = 'Name is required';

if (empty($_POST['email']))
    $errors['email'] = 'E-Mail is required';

if (empty($_POST['subject']))
    $errors['subject'] = 'Subject is required';

if (empty($_POST['message']))
    $errors['message'] = 'Please enter a message';

//Return response
if ( ! empty($errors)) {          //If there are errors

    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors'] = $errors;

} else {

    //Process form
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $re = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $from = 'info@jamescremona.com';
    $to = 'jmscre@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Form submission';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-mail: $email\n Subject: $re\n Message: $message\n";

    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
    }       

    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Form Submitted';

}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should also have a `fail` callback for that `ajax` request.

Comment: whats the content of console.log(data); ?

Comment: just a small simple thing, check your console the problem is here : `$('section#contact form#contactform').hide;
        $('section#contact div.thxform').show;` does functions does not exist on jquery

Comment: This is what u shud have `$('section#contact form#contactform').hide();
        $('section#contact div.thxform').show();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the browser what to expect. So add the header function before your echo

```
header('Content-Type: application/json'); // this line here
echo json_encode($data);
```

**UPDATE**

Also your event.preventDefault(); comes last which should be the first thing you call after $('form#contactform').submit(function(event) { since you want to prevent stuff before the ajax call.

Also you PHP is echoing stuff in either case of the mail functions return value. So the json response is messed up, thus your ajax will not get proper data back.

**UPDATE 2**

I have the strong feeling that your PHP script is throwing errors of some sort. The mail function could be throwing a 530 error for example. So best you disable error displaying in your PHP script. 
**General advice for debugging** this sort of stuff is [web developer browser extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm) to view request/response information.

Try this refactored code please:

```
ini_set('display_errors',0); // disable error displaying. Rather view in logs
$errors = array(); //array to hold validation errors
$data = array(); //array to pass back data

//validate variables
if (empty($_POST['name']))
    $errors['name'] = 'Name is required';

if (empty($_POST['email']))
    $errors['email'] = 'E-Mail is required';

if (empty($_POST['subject']))
    $errors['subject'] = 'Subject is required';

if (empty($_POST['message']))
    $errors['message'] = 'Please enter a message';

//Return response
if ( ! empty($errors)) {          //If there are errors

    $data['errors'] = $errors; // only necessary to set errors

} else {

    //Process form
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $re = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $from = 'info@jamescremona.com';
    $to = 'jmscre@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Form submission';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-mail: $email\n Subject: $re\n Message: $message\n";

    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $data['success'] = 'Your message has been sent!'; // store to $data instead of echo out
    } else {
        $data['errors'] = 'Something went wrong, go back and try again!'; // store to $data instead of echo out
    }

}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

And your javascript snippet in the done function of the ajax call:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#contactform').submit(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault(); // note this one has to be at the beginning of your submit function since you do not want to submit

        var formData = {

            //get form data
            'name' : $('input[name=name]').val(),
            'email' : $('input[name=email]').val(),
            'subject' : $('input[name=subject]').val(),
            'message' : $("#msg").val(),

        };

        $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'sendmail.php',
                data : formData,
                dataType : 'json',
                encode : true
            })

            //Done promise callback
            .done(function(data) {

                //log data to console
                console.log(data);

                //Errors and validation messages
                if (data.success) { // success either exists or not

                    alert("Success! Form should hide now...");

                    $('#contactform').hide(); // an id is (should always) be unique. So you dont need this "section#contact form#contactform". It does not make sense. Also hide and show are functions and need brackets at the end
                    $('div.thxform').show();

                } else { // then its an error

                    alert("An internal error has occured");

                }

            });

    });
</script>
```

And the HTML i used to test this:

```
<form method="post" id="contactform">
Name <input type="text" name="name" value="test"><br>
Email <input type="text" name="email" value="test@localhost.com" ><br>
Subject <input type="text" name="subject" value="subject" ><br>
Message <textarea name="message" ></textarea><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Added the line but still no success

Comment: many thanks for your support! Unfortunately I'm still having no success. 

To troubleshoot, I've made an alert in the done function of the ajax call .. I believe this should give me an alert once the form is submitted and the e-mail is sent, no? In my case I am not getting anything.

Maybe my php code is not informing ajax.done that the process has actually completed?

Comment: I edited the javascript again cause i used your old snippet by mistake...

Comment: I think this is some kind of curse I have ...

I've done a test page and used the code suggested by you .. yet, the form is being submitted, I receive the e-mail but still the form does not change and I don't get any alert. The console does not show any error and the server does not produce any error logs. 

This is driving me insane ...

Comment: You will get there. I updated my answer yet again. Note the fixed jQuery in your done function. Your selectors were still messed up. That is probably why nothing happens even though all went right. If that still does not help, please dump your HTML form.

Comment: Finally we have a success! I've used your latest code and t worked! I've also had another mistake .. at the very top of the php code I've unforseen the <doctype html> line which was causing malfunction. Many thanks for your support .. much appreaciated!

Comment: Nice! Glad we could help. Please do not forget to mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

First error I spotted on your code :

`'message' : $("#msg").val(),`  that is your last item in your array therefore no need for the ',' javascript expect more items after','

You need to check all you js errors in the console, they are there.

then the second error I saw,

`$('section#contact form#contactform').hide;
 $('section#contact div.thxform').show;`
show and hide does not exist in jquery they have `show();` and `hide();` then here : `if (! data.success == true) {}`

This is how your code should look :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('form#contactform').submit(function(event) {

var formData = {

    //get form data
    'name' : $('input[name=name]').val(),
    'email' : $('input[name=email]').val(),
    'subject' : $('input[name=subject]').val(),
    'message' : $("#msg").val()

};

$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'sendmail.php',
    data : formData,
    dataType : 'json',
    encode : true   
})
.done(function(data) {
    //log data to console
    console.log(data);

    //Errors and validation messages        
    if (!data.success) {

        $('section#contact form#contactform').hide();
        $('section#contact div.thxform').show();

        //check which field was wrong and show the user
        if(data.errors.name){

            $('section#contact div.thxform').append(data.errors.name);
        }
        if(data.errors.email){

           $('section#contact div.thxform').append(data.errors.email); 
        }
        if(data.errors.subject){
            $('section#contact div.thxform').append(data.errors.subject);
        }
        if(data.errors.message){
            $('section#contact div.thxform').append(data.errors.message);
        }

    }else{

        $('#successDIV').append(data.message);
    }

}),
.fail(function(data){
    //debugging puporses, all your php errors will be printed in the console
    console.log(data);

});

//Stop form default action
event.preventDefault();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because of 2 tiny mistakes:

1. [js code] Replace `if (! data.success == true)` with `if (data.success == true)`.
2. [php code] add `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before `echo`ing `$data`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is here

```
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
}
```

because you `echo` a string and then a json object. Therefore when you treat `data` response on Javascript, it's not a json object.

Then I would do as follow in PHP

```
if (@mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Form Submitted';
} else { 
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['message'] = 'Internal error';
} 
echo json_encode($data);
```

and in Javascript

```
.done(function(data) {
    if (typeof data !== 'object') {
            alert('Expected data as object - '+typeof data+' received');
            return;
    }
    data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

    //Errors and validation messages        
    if (data.success == true) {
        $('section#contact form#contactform').hide;
        $('section#contact div.thxform').show;
    } else {
        alert(data.message);
    }

});
```

Note that the `@` [operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) before `mail` function will not generate error messages to avoid sending a string on Javascript.

Comment: It's still somehow not getting into the 'if' condition. I'm not getting neither the hide/show on the elements nor the alert message :(

Comment: May you check your browser console to see if you have errors?

Comment: The console shows no errors at all and the e-mail with the form data is sent correctly. I'm starting to think that the problem is either in the way php is sending the data array or how the data is resieved (or how it is assigned to the variable) in Java Script.